# Changing NSIS installer properties

Tags: nsis

I have an NSIS-based installer file called *setup.exe*. When I go into Properties->Details, many details are missing. When I run the installer, UAC requests for elevated permissions (which is ok), but the publisher is "Unknown".

How can I set these properties in the final *setup.exe*, preferably by only changing the NSIS installer script itself?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

For the properties, you need version info table: various [`VIAddVersionKey`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#viaddversionkey) directives and [`VIProductVersion`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#viproductversion). As an example, here's a snippet from the [PortableApps.com Launcher](http://sourceforge.net/p/portableapps/launcher/ci/2.2.dev/tree/Other/Source/GeneratorWizard.nsi#l32):

```
Name "${NamePortable} (PortableApps.com Launcher)"
OutFile "${PACKAGE}\${AppID}.exe"
Icon "${PACKAGE}\App\AppInfo\appicon.ico"
Caption "${NamePortable} (PortableApps.com Launcher)"
VIProductVersion ${Version}
VIAddVersionKey ProductName "${NamePortable}"
VIAddVersionKey Comments "A build of the PortableApps.com Launcher for ${NamePortable}, allowing it to be run from a removable drive.  For additional details, visit PortableApps.com"
VIAddVersionKey CompanyName PortableApps.com
VIAddVersionKey LegalCopyright PortableApps.com
VIAddVersionKey FileDescription "${NamePortable} (PortableApps.com Launcher)"
VIAddVersionKey FileVersion ${Version}
VIAddVersionKey ProductVersion ${Version}
VIAddVersionKey InternalName "PortableApps.com Launcher"
VIAddVersionKey LegalTrademarks "PortableApps.com is a Trademark of Rare Ideas, LLC."
VIAddVersionKey OriginalFilename "${AppID}.exe"
```

As for the publisher field in the UAC prompt, that is different. That's to do with signing. You'll need a digital certificate first, which costs money, and then you can integrate it with [`!finalize`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter5.html#finalize).

Comment: !finalize is for SVN builds only, you have to wait for 2.47 for that command. But there are some other threads on the NSIS forum about signing using !system

Comment: @Anders: ah, I just searched for "nsis sign" (knowing it can be done, our head guy signs our stuff) and found plenty about signing *uninstallers* but nothing much about installers. (Wiki page about signing uninstallers but nothing about signing installers? That should be rectified.) I didn't recognise `!finalise` but thought it might have been introduced in 2.46 and I forgot about it. Considering I had done a Vim syntax file for it and gone through the commands, I think I just didn't really think about it.