# NSIS: Unknown Publiser

Tags: uac, nsis

When I install my application on Win7, Windows shows installation dialog saying 'Unknown Publisher'. What should I do to get rid of it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting the UAC 'Publisher' Field for a NSIS Installer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581570/setting-the-uac-publisher-field-for-a-nsis-installer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply: you need a certificate from the certification authority and sign your binary. The certificate AFAIK is not for free and it is time-limited. For details see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10587106) answer.

Comment: But I can't understand how can I get this certificate ?

Comment: ...And how then can I use this certificate for changing field "Publisher"?

Comment: First you need to buy a code signing certificate (e.g. VeriSign) and sign the installer by that. Publisher field then should be extracted from the digital signature. I was going to sign our installer some time ago but finally we decided not to do it (that's why I wrote 'afaik', according to my research) so I have no experience with final signing process. But there is solution in the linked accepted answer.

Comment: You would need to *buy* a certificate if you want the publisher displayed because you want your certificate to be trusted by Windows. If you use a self-signed or a certificate from non-trusted certificate authority, Windows won't display the publisher.